# Cannot find script file "C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\octave.vbs"

Tags: windows, octave

I get this script error message every time I open Octave (CLI and GUI).
When I "Open file location" it opens the folder and highlights the file "wscript.exe"
I thought octave was missing that file so I reinstalled a couple of times, the same error persists.

Can someone Help me through this error?

Comment: Does `C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\octave.vbs` exist on your system?  Instead of replying with a comment you should edit and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Under `C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0` folder, change `Octave-firsttime.vbs` to `Octave.vbs`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Temporary solution

Find the `octave-firsttime.vbs` file location in your PC, it should be in `Octave` folder and open it.

#### Permanent solution

Right click the octave GUI, properties, check the target location.
Change it from `ocatve.vbs` to `octave-firsttime.vbs` and apply.
Done.